Formal power $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{\pi(k)}. $
Consider the sequence of elements $A_1, A_2, \cdots \in \mathbb{C}[[X]]$ satisfying $\lim A_n = \mathbf{0}$ and $\pi: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ being a bijection. Then,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{\pi(k)}.
$$
where $\mathbb{C}[[X]]$ is the set of formal power series. (Convergence in $\mathbb{C}[[X]]$ is discussed in this reference https://link.springer.com/article/10.1365/s13291-022-00256-6
I have proven that $\lim A_{\pi(n)}=\mathbf{0}.$ Accordingly, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{\pi(k)}$ both converge. Let $A=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k$ and $B=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{\pi(k)}$. How can we prove that $A = B$? I have not yet connected this with the bijection $\pi$.

Hint. For each $d$, there are only finitely many terms in $A_n$'s having non-zero coefficient of $x^d$.

I have proven that $\lim A_{\pi(n)}=\mathbf{0}.$ Accordingly, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{\pi(k)}$ both converge. Let $A=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k$ and $B=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{\pi(k)}$. How can we prove that $A = B$?

Below lemma is an immediate generalization of the ultrametric inequality in $\mathbb{C}[\![X]\!]$:

Lemma. Suppose $A_n \to \mathbf{0}$. Then $|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n| \leq \sup_{n\geq 0} |A_n|$.
Proof. Let $C = \sup_{n\geq 0} |A_n|$. Since $S_N = \sum_{n=0}^{N} A_n$ converges to $S_{\infty} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n$, there exists $N$ such that $|S_N - S_{\infty}| \leq C$. Then by the ultrametric inequality,
$$ \left| S_{\infty} \right| = \left| \sum_{n=0}^{N} A_n + \left(S_{\infty} - S_N\right) \right| \leq \max\left\{|A_0|, |A_1|, \ldots, |A_N|, |S_{\infty} - S_N| \right\} \leq C $$
as required.

Now for each $d \geq 0$, let $N$ be such that
$$ |A_n| \leq 2^{-d} \quad\text{and}\quad |A_{\pi(n)}| \leq 2^{-d} \qquad \text{whenever}\quad n \geq N. $$
Then
\begin{align*}
\left| A - B \right|
&\leq \underbrace{ \left| \sum_{n=0}^{N} A_n - \sum_{n=0}^{N} A_{\pi(n)} \right| }_{(1)}
+ \underbrace{ \left| \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} A_n - \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} A_{\pi(n)} \right| }_{(2)}.
\end{align*}
Since there is a bijection between the terms in $A_n$'s with $> 2^{-d}$ and the terms in $A_{\pi(n)}$'s with $> 2^{-d}$, all of which contained in the range $n = 0, 1, \ldots, N$, those terms are all cancelled out in $\text{(1)}$, leaving only some terms with norm $\leq 2^{-d}$. Hence $|(1)| \leq 2^{-d}$ by the ultrametric inequality. Moreover, by the above lemma, $|(2)| \leq 2^{-d}$. Consequently,
$$ |A - B| \leq 2^{-d+1}. $$
Since this is true for any $d \geq 0$, it follows that $A = B$.

Addendum - A more detailed explanation on $|(1)| \leq 2^{-d}$.
To make this part clearer, we can consider the set $\mathcal{I}$ of indices $n$ for which $|A_k|>2^{-d}$ holds. Then $\pi^{-1}(\mathcal{I})$ is precisely the set of indices $n$ for which $|A_{\pi(n)}|>2^{-d}$ holds.
Now by our choice, both $\mathcal{I}$ and $\pi^{-1}(\mathcal{I})$ are contained in $[N] := \{0,1,\ldots,N\}$, and so, we can further split $(1)$ as
$$
(1)
= \Biggl| \underbrace{ \sum_{n\in\mathcal{I}}A_n
- \sum_{n\in\pi^{-1}(\mathcal{I})} A_{\pi(n)} }_{\text{(1a)}}
+ \underbrace{ \sum_{n\in[N]\setminus\mathcal{I}} A_n
- \sum_{n\in[N]\setminus\pi^{-1}(\mathcal{I})} A_{\pi(n)} }_{\text{(1b)}} \Biggr| . $$
Note that $\text{(1a)} = 0$ by the one-to-one correspondence, meaning that all the terms with norm $>2^{-d}$ cancels out. Also, each of the terms in $\text{(1b)}$ has norm $\leq 2^{-d}$ by our construction. So by the ultrametric inequality (or by our lemma above), we get $|\text{(1b)}| \leq 2^{-d}$.

Thank you very much

@Math_fun2006, I expanded my answer, adding more details on that part.

I think
$|A-B| \le \underbrace{\left|\sum_{n=0}^N A_n-\sum_{n=0}^N A_{\pi(n)}\right|}{(1)}+\underbrace{\left|\sum{n=N+1}^{\infty} A_n-\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} A_{\pi(n)}\right|}_{(2)}$.

@Math_fun2006, You are right, thank you for pointing out my mistake! It is fixed now. (In fact, by the ultrametric inequality, $|A-B|$ can be bounded above by the maximum of $(1)$ and $(2)$, which although do not affect the argument.)

Sangchul Lee, Could you please explain to me how this theorem is proven: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4918139/fubini-for-formal-power-series
