Fubini for formal power series
Let $A_{k,n} \in \mathbb{C}[[X]]$ such that $\lim _{k+n \rightarrow \infty} A_{k, n}=\mathbf{0}$. Prove that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{k, n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{k, n} .
$$
Convergence in $\mathbb{C}[[X]]$ is discussed in this reference https://link.springer.com/article/10.1365/s13291-022-00256-6
I have proven that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{k, n}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{k, n}$ both converge.
A similar result I asked about here Formal power $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{\pi(k)}. $

Since we are not multiplying two of these, it seems overkill to say they are in $\mathbb C[[X]]$.  I did not read the 60-page paper to find the definition of convergence.  Of course Fubini is not true for numbers in general.  So I suppose $A_{n,k} \to 0$ must tell us that the constant term is eventually equal to zero,  the linear term is eventually equal to zero, and so on.  Does this then reduce to the numerical case where only a finite number of terms are nonzero?

First, we prove the following result:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{k, n}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N A_{k, n}, \forall N \in \mathbb{N}, N \geq 2.
$$
Since $\lim _{k+n \rightarrow \infty} A_{k, n}=\mathbf{0}$, it follows that
$$ 
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{k, 1},\quad \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{k, 2},\quad \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (A_{k, 1} + A_{k, 2}) 
$$
all exist. Assume
$$ 
A_1 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{k, 1},\quad A_2 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{k, 2}.
$$
Accordingly, for each $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N_{\varepsilon} \in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that
$$
\left\| A_1 - \sum_{k=1}^{n} A_{k, 1} \right\| < \varepsilon, \quad \left\| A_2 - \sum_{k=1}^{n} A_{k, 2} \right\| < \varepsilon, \quad \forall n \geq N_{\varepsilon}.
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
\left\| A_1 + A_2 - \sum_{k=1}^n (A_{k,1} + A_{k,2}) \right\| &= \left\| \left( A_1 - \sum_{k=1}^n A_{k,1} \right) + \left( A_2 - \sum_{k=1}^n A_{k,2} \right) \right\| \\ 
 & \le \max \left\{ \left\| A_1 - \sum_{k=1}^n A_{k,1} \right\|, \left\| A_2 - \sum_{k=1}^n A_{k,2} \right\| \right\} \\
& \le \varepsilon, \quad \forall n \geq N_{\varepsilon}.
\end{align*}
Thus,
$$ 
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{k, 1} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{k, 2} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (A_{k, 1} + A_{k, 2}) \quad \quad (\star)
$$
For each $N \in \mathbb{N}, N \geq 2$, using the property $(\star)$ $N-1$ times, we obtain
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{k, n} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N A_{k, n}.
$$
Returning to the property that needs to be proven:
\begin{align*}
\left\| \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{k, n} - \sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{k, n} \right\| &= \left\| \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{k, n} - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N A_{k, n} \right\| \\
&= \left\| \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} A_{k, n} \right\|
\end{align*}
Since $\lim _{k+n \rightarrow \infty} A_{k, n}=\mathbf{0}$, for each $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $M_{\varepsilon} \in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that
$$
\left\| A_{k, n} \right\| \le \varepsilon, \forall n \geq M_{\varepsilon}, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}.
$$
For $N > M_{\varepsilon}$, we have
$$
\left\| \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} A_{k, n} \right\| \le \sup_{n \geq N+1} \| A_{k, n} \| \le \varepsilon, \quad \forall k \in \mathbb{N}.
$$
We get
$$
\left\| \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} A_{k, n} \right\| \le \sup_{k \geq 1} \left\| \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} A_{k, n} \right\| \le \varepsilon, \quad \forall N > M_{\varepsilon}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\left\| \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{k, n} - \sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{k, n} \right\| \le \varepsilon, \quad \forall N > M_{\varepsilon}.
$$
In other words,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{k, n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{k, n}.
$$
